# How to remove poop from a cat if it's stuck on some hair that's stuck in her butt?

Tags: cats, health, defecation

Just as the question says my cat has hair coming out of her butt. Human hair. Our mistake. There is poop hanging on the hair. The cat has kittens it should go back to, and I am keeping her in the bathroom until something happens. Some said I should leave the cat remove it but I don't see this happening. This is getting sick, it's making me nervous even more than the poor cat. Maybe not. It's sick. Please help. The kittens arn't crying but the mom wants to go to them. What should I do? I can't let her wipe the poop in the house.

Comment: If you can't let Mom go to her kittens, bring the kittens to her. Regarding the poo, you can either wash it off, cut it off (carefully), or let the cat lick it off. Trimming a cat's fur is tricky, since the skin is thin and very delicate. It sounds as if she is trying to pass a hair-ball.

Comment: Thanks but no it wasn't on her fur it was hanging on a hair which was sticking out of her butt. And my problem was that the cat wasn't able to lick it off.

Comment: Related: https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/4362/how-do-you-clean-poop-out-of-a-long-hair-cats-fur

Comment: Just you have to do is took them a bath and then dont dry them 1rst cut the hair stucks then let them dry there self.

Answer (score 6):

Don't overthink it. Bring scissors and cut the hair, the poo would fall down and you will be done. Don't worry about hair itself though, because it should come out once the cat uses the litterbox the next time. Also keep your house clean and make sure to always use a vacuum cleaner. Lesson learned.

Comment: I agree about cutting the hair. What do you mean 'try to break it' in the case of constipation?

Comment: I read online that if there is poop stuck in the cats asshole then you should break the poop. Disgusting but makes sense. Have you got better solutions? I'm thinking about posing such a question and you can answer there :) k?

Comment: I believe that impacted faecal matter needs a vet's intervention, if it doesn't detach naturally (which most will if it's threaded on a hair -- I've had several cats that eat hair and delivered 'strings of beads'  -- never had to intervene myself, although). Constipation needs to be treated not just worked around..

Comment: Sticky cat feces is common. You can remove it usually. Wear gloves and gently pluck the feces off the cat. If it is difficult to remove or the cat appears to be in pain or there is blood then it is time to go to the vet.

Comment: Yes yes @ColeValleyGirl  this wouldn't happen except if it was a sickness, it's not natural. And so normaly it needs vet advice and veterenarians say that breaking it is what we're supposed to do.

Comment: @toothless199 Constipation is a sickness; eating hair is natural and so is passing it in the faeces. YOu can get exactly the same effect with grass.

Answer (score 0):

OK so I faced this problem today hence why I'm here... I'm not sure if this what you are asking, but here goes ...

I saw my cat poop as I was waiting to clean its litter, but due to a human hair inside the anus, the poop did not drop and to get rid of it, my cat smeared it on the bathroom floor. I immediately took him to the bath and washed his rear end since there was still some poo there and I noticed the hair. So I just slowly pulled it a bit and since the cat had no reaction, it meant it didn't hurt him or anything, so I just quickly pulled it out and once again washed its rear in case.

Answer (score -2):

use a wet cloth to moisten the dried fecal matter in the fur.  Gently comb or work out with your fingers, OH YES wear gloves trim with scissors only when necessary.

Comment: This does not attempt to answer the question, which is about fecal matter stuck to an ingested strand of human hair.